# Print file on client side

Tags: javascript, typescript, filesystems

I am using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to print an object array on the client side (HTML/Typescript).

```
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify( marray)], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
 saveAs(blob, "Data.txt");
```

It works fine. The problem is it downloads in the download folder (by default). I want to add a file path along with its name. Any idea? Or another way to do this job. `fs` is not working in this case. it is not recognizing fs and gives the error `fs.writefilesync is not a function`

Comment: No, you can't set the path for security reasons. You could use this function as an exploit to analyse the filesystem of the client.

Answer (score -1):

1. How do you know what path the user has?
2. It is not safe. There is no way to "climb" the user's file system
3. If you open the source code, you will see the simplest implementation scheme there. It's just a click on a link `download`

   ```
   var a = document.createElement('a')
   // ...
   a.href = blob
   // ...
   a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
   ```

Comment: Is this an answer, a comment or a question?

Comment: this is the answer.

Comment: Why do you ask questions in an answer? What is your answer? How does this answer the question?

Comment: The first point shows that you cannot know the path (file system) of the user. How to specify a path that you cannot know?

Comment: If you don't know the path, you can use a relative path inside the default.

Comment: read the whole answer. The second point explains the first.

Comment: But you could stay inside the default path. "It's not safe" doesn't answer the question. `eval` isn't safe too, but it exists and can be used. "There is no way to "climb" the user's file system" What about `..`?